# How to install Conan build tools in the Jenkins machine

Tags: c++, jenkins, conan

I have an installation of Jenkins on Azure and wish to build a c++ project using Conan. Many examples show the following pipeline command to initiate Conan:

```
def conanClient = Artifactory.newConanClient()
```

however this throws an error:

> sh: 1: conan: not found ERROR: Couldn't execute Conan task.
> RuntimeException: Conan build failed with exit code 127

I assumed the newConanClient() would install Conan but that is not the case as verified by:

> sh 'conan -v' resulting in conan: not found

From the JFrog documentation you would think there shouldn't be any problems as they say:

> There is no need for any special setup for it, just install Conan and
> your build tools in the Jenkins machine and call the needed Conan
> commands.

https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/ci/jenkins.html?highlight=jenkins

So how does one "just install Conan" in Jenkins?

Comment: Is it a Jenkins plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Documentation](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html):

```
Conan can be installed in many Operating Systems. It has been extensively 
used and tested in Windows, Linux (different distros), OSX, and is also 
actively used in FreeBSD and Solaris SunOS. There are also several 
additional operating systems on which it has been reported to work.
```

Based on your OS, you can install from here. newConanClient() method is part of the Artifactory plugin for Jenkins but doesn't install Conan

Now you can verify the installation

```
conan -v
```

and further can execute commands in Jenkins pipeline

```
sh 'conan build .'
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do you install Conan in my Jenkins workspace?

Comment: There are multiple way to do it. eg. using the commands mentioned in doc, create a shell script in jenkins workspace and call it from outside to execute .

Comment: I opened an ssl connection to the Azure VM and installed conan from the command line, and verified the install (i.e. conan --version). However testing conan from the pipeline (i.e sh 'conan --version') throws the error: conan: not found.    So I still do not know how to access conan from the pipeline.